# Better way of writing PHP in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I'm wondering if there is a better way of outputting this code in HTML which includes PHP variables to build an  for a nav bar menu.

```
<ul>
   <?php
     echo "<li><a href='$a->url'>$a->title</a>";
        echo "<ul class='submenu'>";
           echo "<li><a href='$w->url'>$w->title</li>";
           echo "<li><a href='$b->url'>$b->title</li>";
           echo "<li><a href='$c->url'>$c->title</a></li>";
           echo "<li><a href='$d->url'>$d->title</a></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
   ?>
</ul>
```

---

Comment: In my opinion, just writing HTML and then use `<?= $foo ?>` to output PHP variables is much cleaner than echoing blocks of HTML through PHP. It will also enable most IDE's to syntax highlight the HTML, which they tend not to do when the HTML is in a PHP string. With that said, this question is actually off-topic since any answer would be 100% opinion based. Different developers prefer different approaches so stick to the way that makes most sense for you.

Comment: I agree, it looks already much cleaner to just output PHP variables like that. In the end, I was looking for other opinions on formatting as this code works fine, just not pretty to look at. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not conviced that this is 100% opinion based. Would building a very complex html structure of several hundred lines of code be OK to echo in PHP ? That would be a very bad practice and shouldnt be promoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there would be little to no difference in performance you should always try to seperate your HTML and PHP. This leads to a much cleaner code that can be read much more easily.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='<?= $a->url;?>'><?= $a->title; ?></a>
       <ul class='submenu'>
          <li>
              <a href='<?= $w->url;?>'>$w->title</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href='<?= $b->url; ?>'>$b->title</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href='<?=$c->url; ?>'>$c->title</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href='<?= $d->url?>'>$d->title</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Another benefit here : you get your syntax errors in HTML highlighted from your IDE. You missed to close a couple of `<a>` - Tags

Comment: That's a good point! And thanks for pointing out the missing closing tags, despite looking at this code several times I'd never realised!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='<?php echo $a->url; ?>'><?php echo $a->title; ?></a>
    <ul class='submenu'>
      <li><a href='<?php echo $w->url; ?>'><?php echo $w->title; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href='<?php echo $b->url; ?>'><?php echo $b->title; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href='<?php echo $c->url; ?>'><?php echo $c->title; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href='<?php echo $d->url; ?>'><?php echo $d->title; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is valid too, the other solution though looks better in my opinion as I wouldn't want to repeat 'echo' all the times.